# Missing XMLReader Class

Tags: php, xmlreader

I am playing around with parsing spreadsheets and found the spreadsheet-reader class. I installed and have a very simple program written to open and parse an ".ODS" spreadsheet file. When I run it I get the error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'XMLReader' not found in...
```

The line in question:

```
$ss = new SpreadsheetReader("test.ods");
```

So I google around and find out the version of PHP on that system needs to be at least 5.1 for it to use the version of XMLReader built into the core of PHP. I am using 5.4.12 there. I check with php -i and find PHP was compiled with: '--enable-xmlreader=shared'. According to the docs nothing needs to be configured at runtime to enable it.

Where else can I check and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Okay, the solution is because it was built with a shared object file you DO need to modify php.ini: extension=xmlreader.so. I suspect the use of the shared object was left over from a much earlier version of PHP on this server (it originally started with 4.1 or 4.3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is because PHP was built with a shared object file you DO need to modify php.ini: extension=xmlreader.so.